# How to link the title adding a permalink?

Tags: permalinks

How do I change this code to link each title to the post?

Specifically - this line:

```
$dl .= '<dt>' . $query->post->post_title . '</dt>';
```

Thanks,

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_glossary_term',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$dl = '';
$glossary_letter = '';
$active_letters = array( );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->next_post();
    $term_letter = strtoupper( substr( $query->post->post_title, 0, 1 ) );
    if ( $glossary_letter != $term_letter ) {
        $dl .= (count( $active_letters ) ? '</dl>' : '') . '<li id="' . $term_letter . '"><span class="subheading">' . $term_letter . '</span><dl>';
        $glossary_letter = $term_letter;
        $active_letters[] = $term_letter;
    }
    $dl .= '<dt>' . $query->post->post_title . '</dt>';
    $dl .= '<dd>' . $query->post->post_content . '</dd>';
}
$dl .= '</dl></li>';

$ul = '<ul class="letters">';
foreach ( array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
    $ul .= '<li>' . (in_array( $letter, $active_letters ) ? '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>' : $letter) . '</li>';
}
$ul .= '</ul>';

echo '<div id="glossary">' . $ul . '<ul class="definitions">' . $dl . '</ul></div>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked great.  Changed the code per your suggestion.  Louise

Comment: It is not clear who you are talking to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your code strictly you'd want ...

```
$dl .= '<dt><a href="'.get_permalink($wp_query->post->ID).'">' . $wp_query->post->post_title . '</a></dt>';
```

... but you are using the `WP_Query` object in a very atypical way. You are sort-of brute forcing your way through the Loop instead of using the methods and template functions built into the core. For example:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $term_letter = strtoupper( substr( get_the_title(), 0, 1 ) );
    if ( $glossary_letter != $term_letter ) {
        $dl .= (count( $active_letters ) ? '</dl>' : '') . '<li id="' . $term_letter . '"><span class="subheading">' . $term_letter . '</span><dl>';
        $glossary_letter = $term_letter;
        $active_letters[] = $term_letter;
    }
    $dl .= '<dt><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>></dt>';
    $dl .= '<dd>' . get_the_content() . '</dd>';
}
$dl .= '</dl></li>';
```

Or at the very least you can replace `$query->post->` with `$post->` since the `the_post()` method resets the `$post` global to the next post in the loop each time it runs.